# How to get opendir point to my public folder with the relative path "/"

Tags: php, relative-path, image-gallery, opendir

this is kind of odd question, i can't figure out how to use relative path `/`which will not be interpreted as my drive in my current computer.

I'm trying to build a gallery manager for a web site. the path "/" normally points to my public folder when using it in my web site (using a front controller). so technically to display images in my `public/images` i use `/images` now this seems not to work as i'm trying to load all the pictures of a particular folder in my site. am working on `drive D` so `/` points to it, when using opendir.

Is there anything i'm not using properly? or there is a need of an absolute path ? which (the site admin is not necessarily supposed to know).

thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [magic constant](http://php.net/manual/language.constants.predefined.php) __FILE__. In your index.php, `dirname(__FILE__)` will get the path to main directory. Assign it to a constant and use it wherever you like.

Comment: So in this i don't have any way of using relative path but rather absolute path using the root path that the constant you are referring to points to. am i getting it rignt?

Comment: Yea, absolute path is more certain method. Many frameworks use this method to store APPLICATION_PATH for including files.

Comment: So it will be simple in Zend. Constant value APPLICATION_PATH points to application folder. So if you need access to public folder for example you can use echo APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/';